# How to deny view/get operation in openshift via open policy?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, open-policy-agent, rego

We want to disable `oc get/describe` for `secrets` to prevent token login

The current policy prevent create, update, delete but not the viewing of secrets

```
package admission

import data.k8s.matches

# Deny all user for doing secret ops except policyadmin

deny[query] {
    matches[[resource]]

    not "policyadmin" == resource.userInfo.username
    "Secret" == resource.kind.kind

    msg := sprintf("Custom Unauthorized user: %v", [resource.userInfo.username])

    query = {
        "id": "policy-admin-for-secret-only",
        "resource": {
            "kind": kind,
            "namespace": namespace,
            "name": name
        },
        "resolution": {
            "message": msg
        },
    }
}
```

The data in the resource object is just:

> {\"kind\": {\"group\": \"\", \"kind\": \"Secret\", \"version\":
>   \"v1\"}, \"name\": \"s5-token-n6v6q\", \"namespace\": \"demo\",
>   \"operation\": \"DELETE\", \"resource\": {\"group\": \"\",
>   \"resource\": \"secrets\", \"version\": \"v1\"}, \"uid\":
>   \"748cdab2-1c1d-11ea-8b11-080027f8814d\", \"userInfo\": {\"groups\":
>   [\"system:cluster-admins\", \"system:masters\",
>   \"system:authenticated\"], \"username\": \"system:admin\"}

The example in https://github.com/raffaelespazzoli/openshift-opa/blob/master/examples/authorization-webhooks/unreadable_secrets.rego uses the **resource.spec** object, but I don't think it's available in my `input/AdmissionReview` object?

I am using

- minishift 1.24
- openshift v3.9.0+2e78773-56
- kubernetes v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657
- etcd 3.2.16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admission control in Kubernetes does NOT let you control a `get`.  It only lets you control `create`, `update`, `delete`, and `connect`.  The API docs for the [validating webhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#validatingwebhookconfiguration-v1-admissionregistration-k8s-io) and its descendent RuleWithOperations (no handy link) don't make this clear, but the [docs introducing API access](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/controlling-access/#admission-control) state it explicitly.

To control `get`, you need to use [authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/controlling-access/#authorization).  You could use [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) to restrict who can `get` any of the `Secret`s.  To use OPA for authorization you would need the [authorization webhook mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#authorization-modules).

In Andrew's code that you link to, he is using an authorization webhook--not an admission control webhook.  That's why some of the data he is using from `input` isn't the same as what you see from an admission control webhook.  Taking a quick look at his writeup, it seems you need to follow his instructions to [Enable Authorization](https://github.com/raffaelespazzoli/openshift-opa#enable-authorization).